# Different Session for Cakephp Prefix

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm strangling with a simple matter :
How to tell Cake to use a different Session configuration for different prefix (routes).

I have the main domain www.domain.tdl and I don't want the prefix `couriers` (www.domain.tdl/couriers) to use the same Session configuration to avoid Authentification problems : the main domain and prefix use different Authentification configurations.

So, in my App.php, the Session config is :

```
   'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'timeout' => 24 * 60, //in minutes,
        'cookie' => 'app_bo',
//        "cookiePath" => "/mrbo", (tried with or without)
        'ini' => [
            "session.name" => "MR_BO",
        ]
    ],
```

And I thought I could change the config in the AppController of the prefix : 
src/Controller/Couriers/AppController.php

```
    Configure::write('Session', [
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'timeout' => 24 * 60, //in minutes,
        'cookie' => 'app_courier',
        "cookiePath" => "/mrcourier",
        'ini' => [
            "session.name" => "MR_COURIER",
        ]
    ]);
    ini_set('session.cookie_name', 'app_courier');
    ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/mrcourier');
    ini_set('session.name', 'MR_COURIER');
```

Using only `Configure::write` did not work, that's why I added ini_set (seems like it update only internal CakePhp configuration).

By doing so, its works and not works. Indeed, I see that the domain and the prefix don't use the same, but when I tried to log in in the prefix page, nothing, it redirect to itself.

I think it's because CakePHP use Session internally before my settings in the prefix AppController.

**EDIT** 
Here is the Auth component loading : (the one for the prefix is quit the same, only the controller model/controller change)

```
 $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize' => ['Controller'],
            'authenticate' => [
                'Custom' => [
                    'passwordHasher' => [
                        'className' => 'Legacy',
                    ],
                    'userModel' => 'Establishments',
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'login', 'password' => 'password'),
                    "salt" => "salt" // Relative field for SALT
                ],
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'establishments',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'dashboard'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'establishments',
                'action' => 'login',
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: Caould  you post your Auth configuration, that may help

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't there. Just did iit ! but I don't thinks its relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

In your auth configuration, use  `storage` param to change `Session` settings. Use different key for each configuration

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'storage' => ['className' => 'Session', 'key' => 'Auth.Admin'],
         /* ... */
    ]
);
```